# Is it possible to set Screen Flow component visibility based on the UI the user is in currently (Lightning / Classic)?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, component, classic

I have some elements in a screen flow that should only show in Classic UI, and others that should only show in Lightning UI. I haven't found a way to choose which to show based on the current UI the user was in when launching the flow (Lightning or Classic).

Is there any way I could set these conditions? If not, I'll create one flow for Lightning and another one for Classic, just wanted to see if this could be avoided.

**EDIT**: Could my first element in the flow be an apex action that checks the current runtime when the flow is being run, and save that in a variable to use in a decision element / component visibility condition later on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The global variable $User.UIThemeDisplayed gives me the current UI of the user, so I have an assignment element just at the beginning of the flow to assign the "UITheme" variable:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBKGW.png]

And then I can use the value of this variable for element visibility / decision elements. In a decision element I can also get the value of $User.UIThemeDisplayed without having done an assignment before, but when establishing component visibility conditions $User.UIThemeDisplayed is not available for use, so in this case it's necessary to have $User.UIThemeDisplayed assigned to a variable before.